# Why Doesn't jQuery.Find() Return a Collection of DOM Elements from a Document Fragment Cloned From an HTML5 Template?

Tags: jquery, html, templates, find

Why does `$input.size()` output `0` both times to the console given:

```
var $tr = $(CreateLiveNodeFromTemplate("#tplNewMember"));

var $input = $tr.find("td input");

console.log("Number of inputs found using find(): " + $input.size());

$input = $tr.filter("td input");

console.log("Number of inputs found using filter(): " + $input.size());
```

CreateLiveNodeFromTemplate() is defined as:

```
function CreateLiveNodeFromTemplate(tplSelector){
   var docFrag = document.querySelector(tplSelector).content; 
   return document.importNode(docFrag, true)
}
```

The HTML5 Template:

```
<template id="tplNewMember">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" class="chkOwner"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Member</td>
        <td><a href="/scripts/Groups.RemoveMember.asp?id=<%= objGroup.id %>&member=#" class="icon icon-delete"></a></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

I am testing in Firefox 57 and using jQuery 2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `$input.length` instead of `.size()`.

`.size()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. [See documentation for details](https://api.jquery.com/size/)